# Adding multiple patches to SRC_URI in a recipe -- Yocto

Tags: patch, yocto

I would like to know is there an easy way of adding patches to the SRC_URI in Yocto. I am creating a BSP for a customized board using Yocto. I have some hundred plus patches for the Linux kernel and barebox.

To include the patches for the Linux kernel, I have created an .scc file. In the .scc file I have included all the patches required.The SRC_URI option in the kernel recipe looks like:

```
SRC_URI += "https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.0.9.tar.xz \
        file://kernelpatch.scc \
        file://kernel-4.0.9.cfg \
        "
```

For the barebox, I tried to do the same, but it seems it doesn't support .scc files. So now I have included all the hundred plus patches using

`file://patchname.patch`

```
file://patches/0001-drivers.patch \
file://patches/0002-hw_random-C.patch \
.
.
.
.
file://patches/0304-usb-fastbootupport.patch \
```

Is there any option to include all the patches in a single line like in the kernel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your `meta-layer/recipes-kernel/linux` Create a dir like `patches`. Copy all your patches to this `patches` directory.

> create `linux-ti_%.bbappend` file and add below lines

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:"
SRC_URI = "file://patches/* "
```

this will take all your patches at single instance and apply to the kernel.

Comment: No need for the "*", this works: SRC_URI="file://patches"

Comment: bitbake version 1.48.0 actually doesn't support glob expansions anymore: "file:// urls using globbing are no longer supported. Please place the files in a directory and reference that instead."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wildcard to include your files : `file://*` I don't think it's the best choice, but when you have lot of files, it can be usefull.

Comment: I think it doesn't really work robustly, see https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/8443/

Answer (score 0):

As @Pouet_forever "said", this is not best way to wildcards patches files, instead of this You may use bitbake approach with metadata files such like - .inc files. I mean by that You can extract all of them to one variable then include this file in Your main .bb recipe. Please take look at this example of keeping different patches in one file that may be easily used in many recipes:
.inc file with patches - https://github.com/kraj/meta-clang/blob/master/recipes-devtools/clang/common.inc
and usage of that in recipe: https://github.com/kraj/meta-clang/blob/master/recipes-devtools/clang/libcxx_git.bb